# How to connect with a vpn connection without any prompt in windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, vpn

In windows 7 , we can define a hotkey for connect to internet via VPN connection immediately [without any prompt](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-create-a-fully-automatic-internet-connection/), through these Steps:

1. Create shortcut for VPN connection for example in Desktop.
2. Define a hotkey for that shortcut
3. In VPN properties >> options TAB >> dialing options >> uncheck this checkbox : "prompt for name and password..."

This checkbox not exist in windows 8

so we cant define in Windows 8 like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 default VPN - Single Click to Connect](https://superuser.com/questions/106506/windows-7-default-vpn-single-click-to-connect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cache the credentials while creating the VPN connection:

1. Charms bar / Search / Type **vpn** / Click **Settings** / Click **Set up a virtual private network (VPN) connection**:

   [image: 1]
2. Click **Remember my credentials** to save your credentials *on the first successful connection attempt*:

   [image: 2]
3. Now you can click on Charms bar / Settings / Network icon / Click the name of the VPN connection / Click the **Connect** button:

   [image: 3]
   [image: 4]
4. You can create a shortcut to the connection by going to the Charms bar / Search / Type **vpn** / Click **Settings** / Click **View Network Connections**, or by going to Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network Connections:

   [image: 5]
5. If you want a shortcut that automatically dials the VPN connection for you (which the one above won't), follow the steps mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/493749/create-shortcut-to-dial-vpn-connection-in-windows-8)

Comment: is there any way to config that in all client with cmd or powershell or gpo, in active directory?

Comment: As in, automate everything right from creating the VPN connection, saving the credentials, creating the auto-dialling shortcut etc.? I'm not really sure, will have to look into it. Try posting a new question and maybe someone who's done it already can provide a good answer.

Comment: The "Remember my credentials" options has no effect for me, unfortunately. Windows 8 still brings up the "Network Authentication" dialog each time I connect to the VPN.

Comment: Seems like connecting once with the rasphone.exe as mentioned [here](http://superuser.com/a/493750/52817) (and linked in step 5) does the trick. Connecting successfully through the sidebar did not store the credentials for me. But after doing it once with rasphone.exe, it now has the credentials stored even when using the sidebar to connect.