# Single-Click to connet to VPN on Windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, internet

I'm creating a batch file to connect to VPN on Windows 10 by a Single-Click. The VPN is using PPTP. Below is the command I've tried and different problems I faced:

1) `rasphone -d "VPN NAME"**`

Problem: A dialog popped up and ask for confirmation. How can I make it dial automatically without such dialog? I see in this thread ([Windows 7 default VPN - Single Click to Connect](https://superuser.com/questions/106506/windows-7-default-vpn-single-click-to-connect)) and people said we can go into the option tab of the properties for the VPN connection and uncheck "Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc.". However, I can't find such option.

2) `rasdial "VPN NAME"`

Problem: It doesn't work. VPN not connected. A error message was shown telling me the login credential is not correct

3) `rasdial.exe "VPN NAME" "USERNAME" "PASSWORD"`

Problem: Even it is worked, but I don't want to type my password in such command as it may have some security problem. I've already saved my credentials in the VPN property, how can I ask rasdial to use those credentials automatically?

Thanks so much.

Comment: I was looking for this for a while and caved to using option 3 (Which does work) as nobody else has physical access to my machine. I don't like it either, it seems an oversight that the checkbox for "Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc." has been removed in Windows 10.

Comment: Pretty much everything useful has been removed in W10....

Comment: Jonno, you are right, I compared the old VPN property screen with that of Windows 10, and obviously the useful option of "Prompt for name and password, certificate, etc." is just removed. Really having no idea why such important option can be removed, maybe anybody else can have a workaround by cmd or other methods?

Comment: @KitNg Fixed it!

Answer (score 24):

I've solved it without need to mess around, so you can use option 1 since Windows 10 removed this checkbox:

1. Open `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk` in a text editor (Back it up first!)
2. Find `[YOURVPNNAME]`
3. Find `PreviewUserPw=1` - Change it to `PreviewUserPw=0`
4. Save the file

Option 1 should now be working without a prompt.

Comment: Nice solution. Actually I haven't tried it (because I usually not dare to edit any raw codes of a system file...LOL), but I think this solution makes sense. The only concern is if this mod may cause any side effect? As it is not officially supported by the system itself.

Comment: @KitNg I don't think there will be any, it's just a plain text file, like a .ini file. All the GUI interface does is change then I'm the same way, and it's so tiny you can just back it up in the same folder in case anything goes wrong. To be honest, if anything did go wrong, just delete it and re add your VPN again (it automatically generates again). Strangely this file hasn't changed in any recent generation of Windows, so I can't understand why Windows 10 lost the checkboxes, because it still uses their values to work!

Comment: On Windows 10 works like a charm!

Comment: This is so bizarre. Even after setting `PreviewUserPw=0`. `rasphone -d "VPN NAME"` opens the login window.

Comment: @JohnnyO It's entirely possible the behaviour has changed, as this workaround was found about 3.5 years ago. Unfortunately I'm not in a position to test it at the moment, sorry.

Comment: @JohnnyO The `rasphone.pbk` might contains multiple network connections. If you modified the right now, the option works. It works to me on Windows 10 build 19042.